# How to change the text of a tab in a Python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface, ttk

I have a GUI that allows you to create new tabs (using ttk).  After the tab is created the user can open a file and I want the tab name to change to reflect the filename.  Is there a way to change the text of the tab after it has already been placed? Such as a .config(text = '') method?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe this point of documentation can help you: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tab-options

Comment: Thanks! I had skimmed this earlier and missed the tab(tab_id, option=None, **kw) option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use the [`Notebook.tab`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Notebook.tab) method with the corresponding tab id and the `text` keyword. For instance, this changes the text of the first tab:

```
notebook.tab(0, text="New text")
```